OpenOCD Errors finding paths for arm gnu toolchain for STM32 NUCLEO-U575ZI-Q
NUCLEO-U575ZI-Q
Ubuntu VM
Docker, Rust, Embedded Development
Cortex-Debug: VSCode debugger extension version 1.12.1 git(652d042). Usage info: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug#usage
Reading symbols from /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump --syms -C -h -w /home/vboxuser/Desktop/GitHub/RUST/blink/blinky/target/thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf/debug/blinky
Reading symbols from /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm --defined-only -S -l -C -p /home/vboxuser/Desktop/GitHub/RUST/blink/blinky/target/thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf/debug/blinky
Launching GDB: /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin -q --interpreter=mi2
    IMPORTANT: Set "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" in "launch.json" to see verbose GDB transactions here. Very helpful to debug issues or report problems
Error: /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm failed! statics/global/functions may not be properly classified: Error: spawn /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm ENOENT
    Expecting `nm` next to `objdump`. If that is not the problem please report this.
Could not start GDB process, does the program exist in filesystem?
Error: spawn /home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin ENOENT

 *  Executing task: cargo build 

   Compiling nb v1.1.0
   Compiling vcell v0.1.3
   Compiling void v1.0.2
   Compiling bare-metal v0.2.5
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `bare-metal` (lib) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `void` (lib) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `vcell` (lib) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `nb` (lib) due to 1 previous error

 *  The terminal process "cargo 'build'" failed to launch (exit code: 101). 

I tried navigating to and updating my openocd settings via vscode.
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "/home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin",
    "cortex-debug.gdbPath": "/home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin",
    "cortex-debug.openocdPath": "/usr/bin/openocd",
        
    
}

I've also tried solving target issues 'can't find crate for core'
root@8a32e16970a3:/home/app/blinky# rustup target list --installed
thumbv7em-none-eabihf
thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

